# Unable to mount my MP3 player

Tags: 11.04, usb, mount, xubuntu, mp3-player

Ever since I installed Xubuntu Natty, my mp3 player is not mounted any more. `lsusb` also does not list it. Normal USB sticks are normally mounted. How can I re-enable auto-mount for it or mount it manually?

Comment: Please tell us which MP3 player you are using. Some of them don't act as external disks and use a protocol like MTP instead.

Comment: @binfalse: It's an Archos 3 player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug #763227 which you can read on Launchpad [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/763227).

If you update your kernel to 2.6.38-10 or above it should fix the problem.

Comment: Well, it's been nine months now and I always update, so it kinda solved itself.